# COUNT function not counting correctly with DATEDIFF

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008, computer-science

I am sure this is a simple fix, but can not figure it out. I have a COUNT function that needs to count the total number of Rentals. Alone, the function works just fine. I have tried using DISTINCT, tweaking the GROUP BY, and ORDER BY, but to not avail.

When I add the DATEDIFF function to get the NumberofDays rented, the COUNT function does not work the way as intended. I should be getting some results with "2" instead of "1". Note that I need to order by the Rentals.Boat_ID. Here is my code and table results. Thanks

```sql
SELECT
    BOATS.Boat_Brand,
    COUNT(RENTALS.Boat_ID) AS NumberofRentals,
    DATEDIFF(Day, RENTALS.Rental_StartDay, RENTALS.Rental_EndDay)+1) as NumberofDaysRented
FROM RENTALS
INNER JOIN BOATS
    ON RENTALS.Boat_ID = BOATS.Boat_ID 
GROUP BY
    BOATS.Boat_Brand,
    RENTALS.Rental_StartDay,
    RENTALS.Rental_EndDay
ORDER BY
    COUNT(RENTALS.Boat_ID) DESC;
```

| Boat_Brand | NumberofRentals | NumberofDaysRented |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Blue Martin | 1 | 20 |
| Blue Martin | 1 | 35 |
| Boston | 1 | 52 |
| Cherubini | 1 | 11 |
| Dufour | 1 | 10 |
| Eagle Craft | 1 | 19 |
| Motor Yacht | 1 | 17 |
| Motor Yacht | 1 | 47 |
| Grady-White | 1 | 1 |
| Horizon | 1 | 22 |
| Lemsteraak | 1 | 19 |
| Lund | 1 | 64 |
| Mastercraft | 1 | 19 |
| Mastercraft | 1 | 1 |
| Nauticat | 1 | 10 |
| Tracker | 1 | 18 |
| Tracker | 1 | 1 |
| Viking | 1 | 20 |
| Yamaha | 1 | 20 |

EXPECTED TABLE/RESULTS:

| Boat_Brand | NumberofRentals | NumberofDaysRented |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Blue Martin | 2 | 55 |
| Motor Yacht | 2 | 64 |
| Mastercraft | 2 | 20 |
| Tracker | 2 | 19 |
| Boston | 1 | 52 |
| Cherubini | 1 | 11 |
| Dufour | 1 | 10 |
| Eagle Craft | 1 | 19 |
| Grady-White | 1 | 1 |
| Horizon | 1 | 22 |
| Lemsteraak | 1 | 19 |
| Lund | 1 | 64 |
| Nauticat | 1 | 10 |
| Viking | 1 | 20 |
| Yamaha | 1 | 20 |

Comment: Can you please post result you expect?

Comment: Your GROUP BY needs to include all non-aggregated columns in your SELECT statement

Comment: please provide sample data and desired output

Comment: I don't think you need RENTALS.Rental_StartDay, RENTALS.Rental_EndDay. Adding those fields to the group by would only count the number of boats by brand that were rented and returned on the same day. I think you are going to have to do more work and work out the rental timespan per boat and then average that results by brand.

Comment: @AntonínLejsek i have added the expected results thank you

Comment: @eshirvana added expected table results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems like you need to group only by brand and get sum of rented days :

```
SELECT
    BOATS.Boat_Brand,
    COUNT(RENTALS.Boat_ID) AS NumberofRentals,
    SUM(DATEDIFF(Day,RENTALS.Rental_StartDay,RENTALS.Rental_EndDay) + 1)) as NumberofDaysRented
FROM
    RENTALS
    INNER JOIN BOATS ON RENTALS.Boat_ID = BOATS.Boat_ID
GROUP BY
    BOATS.Boat_Brand
ORDER BY
    COUNT(RENTALS.Boat_ID) DESC;
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! You fixed it perfectly. I appreciate your answer a lot.